# Angular2: populate component form dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an angular component (mainComponent) with this template

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #scheduleForm="ngForm" *ngIf="schedule">
    My Main Component 

   <!-- secondaryComponents goes here -->
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default[disabled]="!scheduleForm.form.valid">Submit</button>.
</form>
```

and another component(secondaryComponent).

mainComponent, on init call a webservice that return a number, and i need to add to  mainComponent as many secondaryComponent as returned webservice value.
How can i do?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the main component calls a service that returns a value and you want to pass that value to the secondary component? If so you could just pass it in as an @Input

Comment: no, the returned value tells how many secondaryComponent i need to put inside primaryComponent. For example, if service return 3, in primaryComponent i need to put 3 secondaryComponents

Comment: ah ok i got you now